# backbone comparator performance issue

Tags: performance, backbone.js, comparator

i have a backbone comparator which is basically used to compare the results and sort asc or desc as mentioned in the below code. The issue with the below code is that when the number of itesm to be compared increases there is a performance hit. can any suggest better solution or improve the existing one.

_calculateComparatorResult: function(a, b) {

```
        if (typeof a === 'string') {
            a = a.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (typeof b === 'string') {
            b = b.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (a === b) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (this._sortDirection === this._sortOrder.ascending) {
            return a < b ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            // sorting descending
            return a > b ? -1 : 1;
        }
    },
```

Comment: can you tell us what is the sample size or number records you got to sort at once?

Comment: its around 500 rows in a single column and we have 20 such odd columns

Comment: i guess you would be sorting on single column, is it that way?

Comment: also let me know what you mean by "performance hit" in the question. What is the difference you see in the browser behaviour? because as far as I know, 500 rows is not a big number for browsers today.

Comment: am sorry i was told it could be as many as 10000 rows.

Comment: @Ravi Hamsa yes i am sorting on only single column which has huge number of rows typically 10000 odd such rows....

Comment: None of the front-end technologies are good enough to sort and render 10000 rows flawless on client side, irrespective of its on backbone or whatever. consider paginating data, sorting on server side